# How to delete firebase account when user data is deleted on flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

is it possible to delete firebase account in authentication on flutter? if yes, how to do that? I have been search but not found the way.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(uid).delete().then((_){
   // delete account on authentication after user data on database is deleted            
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Using flutter, if you want to delete firebase accounts together with the associated firestore user collection document, the following method works fine. (documents in user collection named by the firebase uid).

Database Class

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future deleteuser() {
    return userCollection.document(uid).delete();
  }
}
```

Use Firebase version 0.15.0 or above otherwise, Firebase reauthenticateWithCredential() method throw an error like { noSuchMethod:   was called on null }.

Authentication Class

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future deleteUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      AuthCredential credentials =
          EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: email, password: password);
      print(user);
      AuthResult result = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials);
      await DatabaseService(uid: result.user.uid).deleteuser(); // called from database class
      await result.user.delete();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the following code inside the clickable event of a flutter widget tree to achieve the goal;

```
onTap: () async {  
     await AuthService().deleteUser(email, password);
}
```

Comment: I propose to do it in a transaction if at all possible so that you don't end up with a halfway deleted user - especially if you have a slightly complex datamodel with user refs here and there, sub-collections etc. You app might fail just between two of the above wait statement's - then what?

Comment: The class FirebaseUser changed to User.

Comment: What if hte User is Signed with Google Authentication?

Answer (score 18):

Code for deleting user:

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
user.delete();
```

Comment: weird thing for me is that the current user is always returned as null!

Answer (score 8):

To delete a user account, call `delete()` on the user object.

For more on this, see the reference documentation for [`FirebaseUser.delete()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/delete.html).

Comment: How does this work for phone auth tho? I requeres to reauthenticate, but isn't this kinda wierd with phone auth?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code from mine:

```
class FirebaseConnect{

  static final CollectionReference _teacherCollectionRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Teacher');

  Future<TeacherModel> getTeacher(String id) async {
    TeacherModel teacherModel = TeacherModel();
    if (id == '') return teacherModel;
    await _teacherCollectionRef.doc(id).get().then((value) {
      teacherModel =
        TeacherModel.fromJson(value.data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
    });
    return teacherModel;
  }
}
```

And when I wanted to delete that teacher from Teacher collection and from Authentication I used this method:

```
static Future<void> deleteTeacher(String id) async {
 await FirebaseConnect().getTeacher(id).then((value) async{
   await FirebaseConnect().deleteUser(value.email!);
   await _teacherCollectionRef.doc(id).delete();
 });
}

Future<void> deleteUser(String email) async {
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((event) async {
   if (event!.email == email) {
     await event.delete();
   }
 });
}
```