# Delete Firebase User By UID

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to delete a `FirebaseUser` by their uid value in Flutter. I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56437138/9609442) that shows how to delete the User, but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve a `FirebaseUser` by their id. I know once I can get the user I can do the following `fireBaseUser.delete()` using [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/delete.html) method. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Firebase client API on any platform for getting a user by ID.  That operation is reserved for the Firebase Admin SDK only.  What you will have to do is either one of these two options:

- Store the user data you want to get in a database somewhere that's accessible to the client
- Create a backend endpoint that your client can call to get the user data via the Admin SDK

Comment: I'm a little confused on your bullet point 1. You say I store the user data in a database, which is what I'm doing with Firestore, but I need to prevent the user from signing in with their email and password. Also, is your point 2 something that I would use Firebase Cloud Functions for?

Comment: Cloud Function is a possibility, not a requirement.  I don't understand your first question and how it relates to the original question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... What I'm trying to say is I already am storing data such as name, email, uid, and other related info in a collection in my database, Firestore, that is accessible to the client. I'm confused on how that can help me access the FirebaseUser.

Comment: You can't get a FirebaseUser directly, but you can get any information previously found and stored in the database.

Comment: ok, I will look into the Admin SDK... Thanks for your help!